# Using PHP to connect to a user's desktop to retrieve files

Tags: php

Is this even possible:

I would like to write a script that could connect to my PC and read files from a folder, and serv them up. So I could be on a random computer but access my personal files through a php website thats not hosted on the same computer.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. -_-

Thanks

Comment: Take a minute, and think about if someone else did this to you.

Answer (score 3):

PHP can access files on the same computer it runs on using its [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). It can not access files on *other* computers just like that. It basically has the same kind of access you'd have sitting in front of a computer. Any files you can reach on your own hard disk are reachable, files on other computers are only reachable if they're served in some way (network shares, FTP, WebDAV, etc.).

I'm rather unclear about your question, so: If you wrote a script that was running on your desktop computer, and then accessed that desktop computer from somewhere else, your script running on your desktop computer could access the files on your desktop computer and send them to you over the network.
Anything else... not so much.

I'd look into already existing options though, like the aforementioned FTP, WebDAV, VPN, etc..

Comment: I was thinking maybe the ftp functions could assist in this: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

Comment: @Cody Assist in doing what exactly?

Comment: Say my buddy has an ftp server setup on his local machine, I hit this website hosted by another machine that accesses his ftp server via php and it serves up the files on his local machine. Allowing me to download anything he gives me access to.

Comment: @Cody Sure, if you can access your buddy's FTP server from your computer, then so can PHP. So you could use a PHP script on your computer as a proxy to access your buddy's FTP server. `You --(browser)--> Computer --(PHP)--> Buddy's FTP` Your PHP script would need to download files from the FTP server, then pass them on to you (you can download them using a browser).